# Vending machine repeat menu after option is chosen?

Tags: c#

Here is my vending machine. I now need to be able to be able to repeat the menu at the end of the switch to allow the user to go back into the vending machine or exit the program.

Would I use a while loop or an if/else statement. I tried nesting the whole thing in a while loop but then it repeated the the purchase option.

```
        int iNumCrisps = 10;
        int iCrispsBought;

        int iNumChocbars = 20;
        int iChocbarsBought;

        int iNumSweets = 30;
        int iSweetsBought;

        double dTotalMoney = 0;
        int iChoice;


        {
            //display the choices
            Console.WriteLine("Vending Machine");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Buy chocbars");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Buy crisps");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Buy sweets");
            // get the users choice
            Console.Write("Enter your choice: ");
            iChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            //validate user input
            while (iChoice < 1 || iChoice > 3)
            {
                Console.Write("Incorrect option. Please Re-Enter: ");
                iChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }



                switch (iChoice)
                {
                    case 1: //user has chosen chocbars
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.Write("How many chocbars do you wish to purchase?");
                        iChocbarsBought = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                        iNumChocbars = iNumChocbars - iChocbarsBought;
                        dTotalMoney = dTotalMoney + (iChocbarsBought * 0.25);
                        Console.WriteLine("There are now" + iNumChocbars + " chocbars in the machine");
                        break;

                    case 2: //User has chosen crisps
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.Write("How many crisps do you wish to purchase?");
                        iCrispsBought = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                        iNumCrisps = iNumCrisps - iCrispsBought;
                        dTotalMoney = dTotalMoney + (iCrispsBought * 0.30);
                        Console.WriteLine("There are now" + iNumCrisps + " crisps in the machine");
                        break;

                    case 3: //user has chosen sweets
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.Write("How many sweets do you wish to purchase?");
                        iSweetsBought = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        iNumSweets = iNumSweets - iSweetsBought;
                        dTotalMoney = dTotalMoney + (iSweetsBought * 0.20);
                        Console.WriteLine("There are now " + iNumSweets + " sweets in the machine");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("You must enter a number from 1 to 3");
                        break;
                }// end switch



            //validate user input
            while (iChoice < 1 || iChoice > 3)
            {
                Console.Write("Incorrect option. Please Re-Enter: ");
                iChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }


            Console.WriteLine("There is now" + dTotalMoney + "p in the machine");

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I does not look like you ever give the user the option to quit/exit. Possibly add a 4th option to quit/exit, OR ask the user if they want to buy more after the first pass... if they do then display the menu and if not quit/exit.

Comment: Normally vending machines sit at the make your choice option until then next user comes along.  I'm not sure an exit function would be appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are quite new to programming.

What you need to do is place the menu in a function.  This is a block of code that you can call from elsewhere in the code.  I'm guessing this code comes from the main function?

```
private static int ShowMenu ()
{
  int iChoice = 0;
  //display the choices
  Console.WriteLine("Vending Machine");
  Console.WriteLine("1 - Buy chocbars");
  Console.WriteLine("2 - Buy crisps");
  Console.WriteLine("3 - Buy sweets");
  // get the users choice
  Console.Write("Enter your choice: ");
  iChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  return iChoice;
}
```

You would then use this line to show the menu and get the choice

```
iChoice = ShowMenu();
```

You could then look at checking that the user's input was a valid number and things like that as part of this function

Comment: You could also look at creating a class for the items you have in the machine.  A class is a grouping of related values and functions.  You have an item name, an item quantity, a sold quantity and a price for every item in the machine. The menu can then be a loop going through your array of item class instances